# Why is a locally finite measure defined on Hausdorff spaces only?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Recall the definition of a locally finite measure [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_measure#Definition).

Let $(S,\,{\cal{T}})$ be a Hausdorff topological space and let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra containing the topology $\cal{T}$. A measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ is locally finite if $\forall$ point $p\in S$ lies in an open set of finite measure.

${\underline{\mbox{Question 1.}}}~~~~$ Why is it necessary for the topological space to be Hausdorff?

${\underline{\mbox{Question 2.}}}~~~~$ Does this definition imply that a locally finite measure is finite on any open set?

Now recall the definition of compactness:

A set $A\subseteq S$ is compact if any of its open covers contains a finite subcover.

Wikipedia [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Definitions) says that

(a)  A locally finite measure is finite on compact sets.

(b)  The converse also holds, for locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Can you please help me to prove these two statements?

Specifically, will this proof require the Hausdorffness?

Answer (score 1):

Question 2.  No, Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ is locally finite, and $\mathbb R$ is an open set with infinite measure.

a. Suppose $\mu$ is a locally finite measure.  Let $K$ be a compact set.
The collection $\mathscr U = \{U \subseteq S : U \text{ open and } \mu(U) < +\infty\}$ is an open cover of $K$, so it has a finite subcover.  Thus $K$ is contained in a finite union of open sets of finite measure, and then $\mu(K) < \infty$.

b. Use definition of locally compact.

Comment: Start by writing the definition of "locally compact".

Comment: Could you please explain me why in this definition it is necessary for the space to be Hausdorff?